# Unable to get data from populated sqlite database in asset folder

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

The bug is that when I run my code on emulator the app is stopping with an error (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity :
java.lang.NullPointerException: **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference)** in the code `String dbpath =mcontext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();`

**myfragment** :

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {
    private List<ItemRecipe> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecipeAdapter mAdapter;
    private AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;
    databaseHelper db = new databaseHelper(getActivity());

    public FragmentHome() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle a) {
        super.onCreate(a);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

**sqldatabasehelper** :

```
public class databaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "recipes.db";
    public static final String DATABASE_location = Environment.getDataDirectory()+"data/com.recipes.cook/databases/";
private Context mcontext ;
private SQLiteDatabase mdatabase;



    public databaseHelper( Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }


    public  void openDatabase(){

String dbpath =mcontext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
if (mdatabase != null && mdatabase.isOpen()){
    return;
}
mdatabase=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbpath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);


    }


public void closeDatabase() {

    if (mdatabase != null) {

        mdatabase.close();
    }
}



    public ArrayList<ItemRecipe> get_all_name (){
        ItemRecipe itemRecipe=null;
  ArrayList<ItemRecipe> recipslist=new ArrayList<>();
openDatabase();
        Cursor res = mdatabase.rawQuery("select * from recipes",null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        while(!res.isAfterLast()){
           String recipe =res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("name"));
           String img=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("image"));
           String time = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("time"));
            int rating = res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("rating"));

res.moveToNext();
            recipslist.add(

                    new ItemRecipe(

recipe,img,time,rating
                    )


            );

        }

        res.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return recipslist;


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `getActivity()` method it return null because the fragment is not attached yet. Open the database in `onCreate`.

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {
    private List<ItemRecipe> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecipeAdapter mAdapter;
    private AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;

    public FragmentHome() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle a) {
        super.onCreate(a);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        databaseHelper db = new databaseHelper(getActivity());
    }
}
```